# I'm trying to return an array of values for my Excel UDF. I only end up with the first value, and nothing else, why?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, excel-2010

I want my UDF to take a column input and return a string array that I can use as an array formula. The function uses a collection and Resume next to build a collection of uniques (which works), and then I loop through this and add those unique strings to a string array (this also works). Code is as follows:

```
Function FindUniqueValues(columnToCheck As Range) As Variant
'****************************************************************
'** builds a string array of unique values to output somewhere **
'****************************************************************
Dim Col As New Collection
Dim CallerRows As Long
Dim CallerCols As Long
Dim itm
Dim i As Long
Dim CellVal As Variant
Dim stringArray() As String

For i = 1 To columnToCheck.Rows.Count
    CellVal = columnToCheck.Rows(i).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    Col.Add CellVal, Chr(34) & CellVal & Chr(34)
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i

ReDim stringArray(1 To Col.Count) As String
i = 1
For Each itm In Col
    stringArray(i) = itm
    i = i + 1
Next

FindUniqueValues = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(stringArray)
End Function
```

I've set debug points and the `stringArray` has the correct values in it. I've read up on the "I only have one value in my column" problem and the widely accepted solution is transposing it so the array is output as a column not row - this fixed it *once*. It worked, albeit only listing 7 unique strings then repeating them (despite the string array containing 33 entries), and then when I tried entering the formula on a spreadsheet again it hasn't worked since.

The input is a table column, so the function is called as {=FindUniqueValues([table[someColumn])}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code works! *(pasted it in a Standard Module)*:

[image]

I first hi-lighted **B1** through **B9**.  Then clicked in the Formula Bar and then array-entered:

```
=FindUniqueValues(A1:A9)
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

The trick is to hi-light the **B** cells and then enter the formula.  Don't put the formula in a single cell and try to copy downward!

Comment: And I have verified that the use of a table column as the passed range does not cause an issue.

Comment: I've been using Ctrl-Shift-Enter. But the subtelty of using the formula bar to enter it and having the cells preselected was something I missed. Thank you so much, this was driving me insane. Other guides to fix this problem were definitely not as clear as you've been :)

Comment: @lolsail  It is definitely not intuitive......I have stumbled over the same error repeatedly myself in the past.

Comment: @YowE3K  Thanks again....I fixed the typo............... *(my formulas are far from poetic)*

Comment: @YowE3K  The spell-check in the Chrome browser must be very forgiving.

Comment: Could OP re-write (or edit) the UDF to be an array formula? Or are there times where you must enter as Array, even UDFs?

Comment: @BruceWayne  That is a good question...I don't know of any way to avoid the array formula.........unless  you use a sub rather than a UDF..............much easier in a Google spreadsheet => put formula in a single cell and leave empty cells below..........

Comment: I've slightly changed it so it detects whether it was called from the application and does the above. If not it returns it as a variant array to the calling subroutine